# Are these images getting indexed with Google?

Tags: seo, google-index, google-image-search

I've been trying to get certain images from a website (a lot of them actually) to be indexed with Google. The pages containing the images are getting indexed, but I do not see evidence that the main pictures are anywhere in Google images If I enter site:mysite.com/page_url_path, is that not the definitive way to determine what images associated with the page have been indexed? So, if they are not in fact getting indexed, then what factors might cause them to not show up? "Fetch with Google" in webmaster tools shows that the scraper is getting a page that has the appropriate "img" tag with the correct URL in the source. The images are all hosted remotely with Cloudfront.

I appreciate any help or insight anyone could provide on this issue!

UPDATE: What is the reliable way to determine if an image has been indexed if it is not hosted on the site?

Comment: Your images are not on your site so site:mysite should not work to find the images.

Comment: search for the image in google image search by name? but you probably have tried that.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, images not hosted on your site will not be indexed, categorised and referred to your website by Google. In other words, Google will grant the search result of the image to the domain/URL on which the image is **actually hosted**.

The only use to your here is the fact that the image `alt` and `title` tags are on your page's HTML code and will be optimized for those keywords.

For your reference, run a search on Google for an image and view the image URL on preview, it always shows the hosted URL and not the image display URL.